# is there a way to query OData with a linq query

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core, odata, .net-6.0

I'm using `[EnableQuery]` and returning an `IQueryable` from my api controller like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Category> Get()
{
    return getCategories().AsQueryable();
}
```

Is it possible to consume this odata url using `linq`, e.g. something like:

```
var res = await getOdata("Category").Where(item => item.Size > 100).ToArrayAsync();
```

does something like this exist ? I could only find examples of odata api's being built and consumed via string parameters but no linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are mainly 2 ways to add Query Options to a DataServiceQuery
>
> 1. Using AddQueryOption method.
> 2. Using strongly typed C# LINQ query methods.

So you can query OData with LINQ query. For more details, you can check below official doc.

[LINQ Query Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/query-options#filter)